# jQuery change background with <input type="range">

Tags: jquery, css, click

How do,

I've been teaching myself a little basic jQuery recently, doing so I stumbled across the idea of adding a slider to change the background colour of my page. I've figured out the .click and .css parts ok - it works fine with a div, which is incredibly exciting; but I'm having a little trouble implementing it using a range. I think it's just a problem with targeting but I've hit a bit of a wall and would very much appreciate your assistance :)

Stuck a demo page up here: http://www.weleasewodewick.com/redesign2/test.php

Page is making use of http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/rangeinput/index.html alongside the default jQuery library.

**Script:**

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(function(){
        $(":range").click(function () {
            $("body").css("background","red");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Range:**

```
<input type="range" name="background_pick" min="1" max="5" step="1" value="3" />
<script>$(":range").rangeinput();</script>
```

Hope this is clear enough - if you need any more detail just let me know.

Comment: Should be noted, the script under the input itself is the activation for the jQuery tools stuff.

Comment: There's no need for both `document.ready` and `$(function(){` wrappers, you only need one or the other.  Also `:range` isn't a [valid selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (not normalized cross-browser anyway).  Last, which browser are you trying this on?

Comment: @NickCraver - thanks for the clarification - early days for me with jQuery so it's appreciated. Using Chrome at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Im not exactly sure what you are trying to do here but t seems the range input doesnt have a click event. Change it to "change" and it works.

```
$(":range").change(function () {
    $("body").css("background","red");
});
```

Comment: That does indeed appear to work. Will combine this with a new selector as per Nicks comment ... cheers Fabian!